# Is there a way of putting custom buttons/widgets in a YouTube fragment?

Tags: android, google-api, fragment, android-youtube-api

I want to put my own widgets on a YouTube fragment. I have used a YouTube fragment and a DialogFragment. I have tried to achieve it in many ways, but the YouTube fragment overshadows the widgets in the DialogFragment everytime it is switched to fullscreen. *In other words, the DialogFragment gets hidden*. Is there any way to put the dialog fragment over the YouTube fragment?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet... trying to find